# How to disable SimplePagedResult control in OpenLDAP running in docker container

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to reproduce issue when LDAP server does not support SimplePagedResult control. To do so I deployed Open LDAP image into my local Docker. Successfully run it and add users to directory using Apache DS.

Now I am stuck how to disable SimplePagedResult control (OID = 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319). Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using static configuration (aka slapd.conf) add this line:

```
limits * size.prtotal=disabled
```

If using dynamic configuration (aka cn=config) add this attribute:

```
olcLimits: * size=unlimited  size.prtotal=disabled
```

Then *slapd* responds with *adminLimitExceeded*(11).

Some LDAP clients try to detect which controls are supported by reading attribute *supportedControl* in the server's *rootDSE*. So sometimes it's useful to deny access to certain values with a *val.regex* ACL.